# Phasing in phase

Tags: magic-the-gathering

According to the mtg rules, permanents phase in or out before you untap your permanents. Is there a moment between phasing in and untapping when an opponent can try to destroy a permanent while you are still "tapped"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, players do not receive priority during the untap step, which is the first step of the turn, so no spells or abilities can resolve then:

> 502.3. No player receives priority during the untap step, so no spells can be cast or resolve and no abilities can be activated or resolve. [...]